# Semaphore Suggestion in Swift 4 and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

I am currently trying to decide how to implement semaphores in my iOS application. I have a table view where each row represents a song. Each row contains a count of how many votes that song has received and an up and down arrow to vote. Each song has its own count so Song 1 can have 0 votes and Song 2 can have 5 votes. Currently, if multiple people are voting on Song 1 at the same time, I run into issues because the number does not get updated correctly.

I was planning on using semaphores to fix this issue. However, I'd like there to be a semaphore for each row in the table view. Is this possible? Any suggestions on how to better fix this issue?

Comment: Just use a concurrent queue and update the database from the queue.. Why do you need 1 semaphore per row? What do you mean multiple people voting at the same time?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! If there is 1000 songs and 1000 people voting, creating one semaphore will have 999 people waiting even if they are all voting on different songs. Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there is 1000 songs and 1000 people voting, creating one semaphore
>   will have 999 people waiting even if they are all voting on different
>   songs. Correct?

If you have 1-million people, you'd have 1-million semaphores to synchronize your database? Think about scaling..

You need to use a `Transaction` operation for your database. See here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions

The above example seems to be the same thing you're attempting to do (voting with stars and incremental counters).

You cannot synchronize a remote database with a sempahore on the client-side anyway.. Unless I'm mistaken and your DB is local. In any case, a Transaction operation is the way to go.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Not so sure how I missed it. Thanks so much!